# How to populate my checkbox in my view.js from an array in my controller.js? (Block Kit Slack)

Tags: javascript, arraylist, aws-lambda, slack-commands, slack-block-kit

How do I populate this checkbox with the data from an array in my controller?

`My-view.js`

```js
function arrayBlock() {
    return createModalBlock('Engage', [
        {
            type: 'section',
            text: {
                type: 'mrkdwn',
                text: 'This is a section block with checkboxes.'
            },
            accessory: {
                type: 'checkboxes',
                options: [
                    {
                        text: {
                            type: 'mrkdwn',
                            text: 'Option 1'
                        },
                        description: {
                            type: 'mrkdwn',
                            text: 'user description'
                        },
                        value: 'value-0'
                    }
                ],
                action_id: 'checkboxes-action'
            }
        }
    ], {
        close: {
            type: 'plain_text',
            text: 'Close',
        },
    });
}
```

controller.js

```js
arr = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4", "option 5"]
```

Checkbox options should be option 1, option 2, [...]
[image]

Comment: Please paste code as text instead of pictures  Also, please ensure that community can reproduce the problem with code you share.

Comment: Answered it! Make sure to mark it as solved if it does help with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't copy your code, since you posted it as a `Image`, but this is how you can do it:

```js
arr = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4", "option 5"]

let arrayResult = arr.map((option, optionID) => {
    return {
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": option
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": optionID
        },
        "value": `value-${optionID}`
    }
})

console.log(arrayResult)
```

Using `arr.map()` will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello William, thanks for answering my question. Just wanted to ask if I should apply this in my view.js or controller.js? thank you!

Comment: On `My-view.js`, on the options part.